# Black screen after shutting lid on Ubuntu

Tags: suspend, shutdown, lid

When I close the lid on my HP computer and re-open it then screen remains black and no matter what button I press - I always have to resort to holding the powerbutton down for 10 seconds to shutdown the computer. This results in me losing all of my unsaved work and closing all of the running applications.

I have tried multiple ways to fix this. Editing the grub file, installing gnome screensaver, but nothing seems to work.

The Computer is a HP 245 G6 Notebook PC and it is installed wit Ubuntu 20.04.4.

Please help me to fix this issue as it is so irritating,

Thanks a lot,

Josh.

Comment: You've provided no OS/product/release details.. nor given any clues as to any exploration you've performed.  Can you safely restart using SysRq commands direct to the kernel? or are you using a release where this is disabled?  Were you able to direct the kernel to kill Xorg? switch to text terminal & explore what's occuring etc..  Why do you only mention the *to be avoided* use of the power key?  are you getting kernel panics?

Comment: The reason I am avoiding use of the power key is because when I do hold down the power key it shuts down my computer terminating any running applications. I will update the question with my computer specs.

Comment: You're performing a *unclean* shutdown without any protection... why not use text terminal?  provide direct commands (using SysRq keys) to the kernel to safely dismount file-systems, shutdown Xorg (Wayland? you've provided no specifics), reboot/shutdown or whatever you want... all of which can be done safely.

Comment: I cannot use the terminal as the Screen is Black! When the screen is completely black - how do you suppose I should use the terminal? To re-clarify the question; The computer works completely fine. I then close the lid of the laptop and after re-opening the lid, the screen remains black. I click the mouse, click the power button, and a key on the keyboard however it doesn't turn back on. The only way to get the computer screen to turn back on is to hold the power button for 10 seconds and then turn the computer back on. This terminates all running applications.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F4 doesn't switch you to a text terminal?  (ie. even with a stuck GUI where you cannot use a gui-terminal, text terminals being different things should still be available).  With Ubuntu 20.04 (an *older* system; four releases ago) there is no restriction on SysRq commands so you can also directly instruct the linux kernel to perform functions bypassing any stuck GUI etc..  Grab a phone, search "magic sysrq" and use the wikipedia entry to look for clues - it's Linux and not Ubuntu specific (requires real keyboard so won't work on android phones or any device using on-screen keyboard)

Comment: Ok thankyou, I will try this later and give you a response soon. Thanks.